# How to parse this URL in java

Tags: java, apache, url, httpclient, urlencode

I have a URL like this

```
http://my.my.info/action/doning/something?mailParams=iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=
```

I need it in key value pair not as a query string.

my out put should be

```
mailParams = iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=
```

i could not parse this string since the above is encoded. I have used `URLEncodedUtils` to parse this but it returns

```
mailParams = iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ vx43P4g umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW KjUi3JubtJT 0F7p wPHEpTRwJJ O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA
```

which is not at all relevant can some one help me to do this?

Comment: I think plus sign translates to a space

Comment: I know that the plus is translated i need how to fetch that parameter from that string..

Comment: and equal signs must be escaped in an url

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you want the + or you want it decoded, correctly, to a space. And if you want the +, why? It wasn't sent that way, and if it was it shouldn't have been: don't compensate for a bug by adding another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need to split the link to get the parameters

use [**`String#split`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192011/how-to-parse-this-url-in-java/23192088?noredirect=1#comment35472743_23192088) which takes the regex as a arguments

```
String link="http://my.my.info/action/doning/something?mailParams=iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=";
        String[] mailparams=link.split("\\?");
        System.out.print(mailparams[1]);
```

You can also 
Use [**`URL#getQuery`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html)

```
String link="http://my.my.info/action/doning/something?mailParams=iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=";
         URL aURL = new URL(link);
        System.out.println( aURL.getQuery());
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
mailParams=iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=
```

Comment: @ashokramcse it will returns your excepted output isn't ?

Comment: K what happens when i split your query using =

Answer (score 3):

Try using java.net.URL

A sample code below.

```
    URL aURL = new URL("http://my.my.info/action/doning/something?mailParams=iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=");

    System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
    System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
    System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
    System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
    System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
    System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
    System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
    System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL aURL = null;
try {
    aURL = new URL("http://my.my.info/action/doning/something?mailParams=iCgGugAIdMW3CqkYbZ/dGYVqljerVjzbKLvTQCyuosHzxisIrgYf8rcKqRhtn90Z0eVGZ+vx43P4g+umFmddNdDufWv/nDwbCgqBwHs9OYVd5g4VKuFO4jTfF1NiW+KjUi3JubtJT+0F7p+wPHEpTRwJJ+O0eevojx6DioK3cLGejz5UdfIrqzOVNT05TaPKFie4yZxbXfA=");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(aURL.getQuery());
```